# EXCEL VBA: How can I reset a radio button to a default selection upon pressing a Command Button?

Tags: vba, excel

I am having some difficulties trying to determine how I can reset a radio button to "OptionButton1" when I click "CommandButton1".

Here is my coding for the buttons (following is listed in "Sheet3" code):

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    ' MED Tab - Sort Button
    ' Returns view back to default, then sort data
    On Error Resume Next
    Call Medical.MED_Sort
End Sub

Private Sub OptionButton1_Click()
    ' MED Tab -
    On Error Resume Next
    ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
End Sub

Private Sub OptionButton2_Click()
    ' MED Tab - Show Verified Only
    On Error Resume Next
    ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
    Call Medical.VRFD_ONLY
    Call Module1.FirstVisibleCell
End Sub

Private Sub OptionButton3_Click()
    ' MED Tab - Show NO Scores
    On Error Resume Next
    ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
    Call Medical.No_Scores
    Call Module1.FirstVisibleCell
End Sub

Private Sub OptionButton4_Click()
    ' MED Tab - Show With Scores
    On Error Resume Next
    ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
    Call Medical.With_Scores
    Call Module1.FirstVisibleCell
End Sub
```

and here is the Macro for the "CommandButton1" (in the "Medical" Module):

```
Sub MED_Sort()
'
' MED_Sort Macro
'

'

        ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False

    Columns("A:I").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Med").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Med").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("H:H"), _
        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Med").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("F:F"), _
        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Med").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("D:D"), _
        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Med").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("B:B"), _
        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Med").Sort
        .SetRange Range("A:I")
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

So in the first code block, you can see that basically the OptionButton1's job is literally just to turn off any Auto Filters (so clicking this radio button is basically a reset).
Also, the CommandButton1 is an AutoFilter reset as well, but it will sort all the data to my default sorting preferences. Because CommandButton1 basically does what OptionButton1 does, plus it also sorts, when I press the CommandButton1, I need it to also automatically select OptionButton1 in the event any other buttons are already selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Davis,
You can use `OptionButton1.Value = 1` to programably select one radio button or the other. If I've understood you question correctly, this should do it for you. If I've misunderstood you, please let me know.